# Open an iframe in a modal window where iframe src=variable Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, iframe, modal-dialog

I can open an iframe in a modal window with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
 <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 54.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; min-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php' style='border:0'></iframe></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Where the iframe `sar` link is hard coded.
But I need to add the iframe link as a variable from a gas function.

I have

Gas

```
function openPopup() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
      html.mylink = 'https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php'
      html.setHeight(2000)
      html.setWidth(5000)

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 .showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME), 'Dialog title');
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
 <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 54.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; min-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src=<?= mylink ?> style='border:0'></iframe></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

I get the Error.

```
Error Exception: Malformed HTML content: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
 <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 54.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; min-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src=<?= mylink ?> style='border:0'></iframe></div>

 </body>
</html>.
```

Clearly it is not liking the `src=<?= mylink ?>`

How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This fixed it `var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a dialog without errors but I don't see anything in the dialog.  Perhaps you can take it to the next step on your own?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 54.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; min-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style>
    <div class='embed-container'><iframe src=<?= mylink ?> style='border:0'></iframe></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

GAS:

```
function openPopup() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah3');
  t.mylink = "'https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php'"
  let html = t.evaluate();
  html.setHeight(2000);
  html.setWidth(5000);
  html.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative Method

> This may not be the most straighforward way, but you could try to pass the link instead using the Google Apps Script [`Class google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)). See this sample tweaked script below:

***GS File***

```
function passLink(){
  return 'https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php';
}

function openPopup() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
      html.setHeight(2000)
      html.setWidth(5000)

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 .showModalDialog(html.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME), 'Dialog title');
}
```

***HTML File***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <style>
    .embed-container {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 54.25%;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      min-width: 100%;
    }

    .embed-container iframe,
    .embed-container object,
    .embed-container embed {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 
  </style>

  
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(link) {
      var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
      iframe.src = link; 
    }).passLink();
  


  <div class='embed-container'><iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" id="myIframe" src='' style='border:0'></iframe></div>

</body>

</html>
```

### *Demo*

[image]